# Why does this code work on my test server but not on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, testing, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KeithDickens/t2t9pvz4/19/

As it's written it works fine on my Intranet test server but JSFiddle it does nothing.  Am I missing a nuance of JSFiddle?

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Add More" onclick="nextLine();">
<div id="test1">
    Test1:<input type="text">
    Test2:<input type="text">
    Test3:<input type="text">
</div>

<br />
<br />
<div style="display:none" id="test2" name="test2">
    Test1:<input type="text">
    Test2:<input type="text">
    Test3:<input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Remove">
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div style="display:none;" id="test3" name="test3">
    Test1:<input type="text">
    Test2:<input type="text">
    Test3:<input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Remove">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    var xy = 2;
    var divid = "";

function nextLine() {
    divid = "test" + xy;
    document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'block';
    xy++;
    }
```

Comment: change the onload to no wrap in<head>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zmsak3wj/ see on left  __"no wrap - in head"__

Comment: Thank you to everybody that answered.  I'm learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because jsFiddle is adding `window.onload = function() {}` around your JS, which causes the function in your onClick attribute to no longer be in global scope.

If you look on the top left it does this by default. In order for it to work you'll have to select **No wrap - in `<body>`**: http://jsfiddle.net/t2t9pvz4/23/

Comment: In order to see what I mentioned, right click on the results pane, select **This Frame** and then click **View Frame Source**.

Comment: I also didn't mean that you **have** to select the *No wrap - in body* option, because *No wrap - in head* also works, just FYI.